# Integration between Apache and Tomcat - mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured. (It was what tomcat server told me)

Doing the tasks of integration between Apache and Tomcat I got 50%. I mean, I got Apache up and running(because when I loaded the browse was fine) after configuration, but when I started Tomcat I got an error as you can see below:

My products versions are:

- Apache 2.2.25 (win32)
- Tomcat 7.0.47 (w x86)
- mod_jk.so 1.2.37

Apache httpd.conf:

> LoadModule jk_module "C:\Program Files\Apache Software                Foundation\Apache2.2\modules\mod_jk.so"
>       JkWorkersFile "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\conf\workers.properties"
>       JkLogFile "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\conf\from_apache_mod_jk.log"
>       JkLogLevel Info
>       JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
>       ServerName localhost
>       JkMount /examples ajp13
>       JkMount /examples/* ajp13

Tomcat server.xml:

> <Listener className="org.apache.jk.config.ApacheConfig" modJk="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\modules\mod_jk.so" />
>       </Engine>

Dump File:

```
Nov 25, 2013 11:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Informações: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.4.8.
Nov 25, 2013 11:35:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Informações: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Nov 25, 2013 11:35:25 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
Grave: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jk.config.ApacheConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

Nov 25, 2013 11:35:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Advertência: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (141, 143) : org.apache.jk.config.ApacheConfig
Nov 25, 2013 11:35:25 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
Grave: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jk.config.ApacheConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:679)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Nov 25, 2013 11:35:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Advertência: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (141, 143) : org.apache.jk.config.ApacheConfig
Nov 25, 2013 11:35:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Grave: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

Comment: The server.xml is: <Listener className="org.apache.jk.config.ApacheConfig" modJk="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\modules\mod_jk.so" />
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>  I mean, Looking for configurations I saw a lot of possibities to configure it. I prefered the instructions inside apache web site, but Tomcat doesn't load. Can someone help me?

Comment: I found out this document that explain, however I coundn't understand. How can I integrate Tomcat 7 and Apache 2.2 ? http://faqcluster.com/question1875309190

Answer (score 1):

Download tomcat-jk2.jar file and put it in Tomcat's lib folder.This will solve your problem.
You can download tomcat-jk2.jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/t/Downloadtomcatjk2jar.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Marcos,

that message you read is on the tomcat user mailing list. They are saying that the `ApacheConfig` class has been removed from tomcat7 so trying to configure a listener with it in the server.xml is going to throw the `ClassNotFoundException`. So essentially you have to remove that `Listener` config from your `server.xml`.

You have to put the 'mod_jk.conf' file, if you already have one, in the Apache config directory - I'm not sure about windows, but in linux there is a 'conf.d' or there is a `mods-available` directory (if you put it in the latter, you have to enable the module with `a2enmod`)

Failing that you can just add it to the bottom of your main Apache config file.

For what to put in the config there, check out [configuring tomat's server.xml file with auto generating mod_jk.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405448/configuring-tomats-server-xml-file-with-auto-generating-mod-jk-conf)