# configuring tomat's server.xml file with auto generating mod_jk.conf

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, centos6, mod-jk

I am using `apache (2.2.15)` and `tomcat6 (6.0.24)` on `CentOS 6.4` and would like to use the feature with tomcat server that generates the mod_jk.conf file automatically by adding:

`<Listener className="org.apache.jk.config.ApacheConfig" workersConfig="/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/jk/workers.properties" modJk="/usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so" />`

in tomcat's server.xml file just before `</Engine>` tag.  It work just fine and generates the mod_jk.conf file for me. Here is a copy of the generated mod_jk.conf:

```
########## Auto generated on Thu Dec 05 08:32:05 PST 2013##########

<IfModule !mod_jk.c>
  LoadModule jk_module "/usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so"
</IfModule>

JkWorkersFile "/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/jk/workers.properties"
JkLogFile "/usr/share/tomcat6/logs/mod_jk.log"

JkLogLevel emerg

<VirtualHost localhost>
    ServerName localhost

    JkMount /CallOffice ajp13
    JkMount /CallOffice/* ajp13

    JkMount /Diag289 ajp13
    JkMount /Diag289/* ajp13
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that I need the apps under tomcat **to be accessible by IP or DNS name** and can't get at my apps under tomcat through apache `(http://serverIP/CallOffice/CallOffice.jsp)`. According to the documentation here:

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html

mod_jk.conf can have a VirtualHost tag like:

```
# All URL goes to tomcat except the one containing /home
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

For background info, the following in server.xml generates the `<VirtualHost localhost>` tag in mod_jk.conf when it is auto-generated:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"          xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

Under this configuration, you can't access tomcat apps through apache unless you're on the server using localhost.  To get a configuration that works, I have to add:

`<Host name="*:80"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">`

to tomcat's server.xml file. This makes the mod_jk.conf file look like this:

```
########## Auto generated on Thu Dec 05 08:38:52 PST 2013##########

<IfModule !mod_jk.c>
  LoadModule jk_module "/usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so"
</IfModule>

JkWorkersFile "/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/jk/workers.properties"
JkLogFile "/usr/share/tomcat6/logs/mod_jk.log"

JkLogLevel emerg



<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *

    JkMount /CallOffice ajp13
    JkMount /CallOffice/* ajp13

    JkMount /Diag289 ajp13
    JkMount /Diag289/* ajp13
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost localhost>
    ServerName localhost

    JkMount /CallOffice ajp13
    JkMount /CallOffice/* ajp13

    JkMount /Diag289 ajp13
    JkMount /Diag289/* ajp13
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration works and I can get to my apps `(http://serverIP/CallOffice/CallOffice.jsp)` but when I start up tomcat I get the following error:

```
Dec 5, 2013 8:38:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext preRegisterJMX
INFO: Error registering ctx with jmx
StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[*:80].StandardContext[/CallOffice] null
javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ':' in value part of property
javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ':' in value part of property

Dec 5, 2013 8:38:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ':' in value part of property at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:617)

Dec 5, 2013 8:38:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Dec 5, 2013 8:38:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext registerJMX
INFO: Error registering wrapper with jmx
StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[*:80].StandardContext[/CallOffice] null
javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Object name cannot be null
javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Object name cannot be null`
```

Tomcat hates seeing any host tag in `server.xml` that has an '*' in it.  But this is needed for my deployment where users sometimes use IP address to access the apps.  I know I can just use a static version of mod_jk.conf to get what I need, but I would like to use an auto-generating mod_jk.conf file because new .war files added to tomcat will be configured automatically in mod_jk.conf without having to update a static mod_jk.conf file.

Any ideas here?? Even though I get the errors in Tomcat's log file when starting, my apps still work..Ignore tomcat's errors?? or go with a static mod_jk.conf file with no virtual tag or `<VirtualHost *:80>` to get what I want??

Comment: Disappointed not to see any answers on this one! I'm doing this on Debian right now, so I'll see if I can find anything useful and report back. I found the tomcat.apache.org doc confusing to say the least, and I figure it's way out-of-date too.

Comment: @Adam I had to go with a static mod_jk.conf file for now.  I hope you're able to find a solution.  I don't trust those apache docs either, they're usually wayyyyy out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here's your answer - go with a static mod_jk.conf file.

[Tomcat user list archive](http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/111442tc89/tomcat7-with-mod-jk)

The tomcat developers considered this ApacheConfig auto-generation functionality not to be good enough for production, and in tomcat 7, it was removed. Presumably the issue was too complex and not high enough priority.

Comment: Good find Adam. That explains it perfectly. Hopefully, others won't have to waste as much time on it as we did...